# Why my code doesn't work for driving Android phone's LED?

Tags: android

```
package com.example.phoneled;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class LedOnOff extends Activity {
    ToggleButton tb;
    final int ID_LED = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_led_on_off);

        tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notification = new Notification();
                notification.ledARGB = 0xFF0000; // 0xFF0000 red，0x00FF00 green
                notification.ledOnMS = 100;
                notification.ledOffMS = 200;
                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
                nm.notify(ID_LED, notification);
//              nm.cancel(ID_LED);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_led_on_off, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Above code is for driving LED of my Android phone: HTC Sensation XE G18. But it does not work. No error or warning is given, but the real LED doesn't blink (neither turns red color) at all. You could find similar codes on internet everywhere. I don't know what I miss. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Not every device has an LED. Those that do have an LED do not necessarily support them for notifications. Those that do have an LED for notifications might be using the LED for something else (e.g., charging status) and therefore not flash it when your app runs.

Comment: The reason was found and you are right. I should unplug the charger and then do the test. Thank you very much! **This is the right answer.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple problems I noticed right away:

1. You must set certain members of the Notification class that are not set by default, for instance [`Notification#icon`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#icon):

   > **icon**: The resource id of a drawable to use as the icon in the status bar. This is required; notifications with an invalid icon resource will not be shown.
2. My HTC, like many other devices, doesn't accept custom LED patterns or colors. It will only use the OS' defaults...

Comment: Notification icon is not critical, and above code can work without charger plugged in. But you are right, the color cannot be changed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your color to `0xFFFF0000`. It's supposed to be ARGB, and according to the docs:

> To turn the LED off, pass 0 in the alpha channel for colorARGB or 0 for both ledOnMS and ledOffMS.

Comment: I tried the value, but it seems that value does not matter. It is always light green. Thank you!